# How to find the cause of HTTP 500 Error for GKE deployment?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, http-status-code-500

I have deployed a Spring Boot application onto a Google Kubernetes Engine workload. First, I pushed an image to Artifact Registry. Then, I ran the image using the docker run command in the gcloud command line. My GET request worked perfectly fine then, but once I deployed the image to a Kubernetes workload, the same GET request to the LoadBalancer returned a 500 Internal Server HTTP error.

Everytime I try going on Google's Error Reporting, it tells me to setup Error Reporting, but I don't really understand how to, and besides I thought HTTP errors automatically went to Error Reporting.

I'm sorry if there's too many extra details, I mainly want to know how to see the cause of an HTTP 500 error on a GKE deployment?

Comment: Are you using a LoadBalancer service or are you using Ingress?

Comment: @GariSingh I am using LoadBalancer not Ingress. The accepted answer allowed me to see the logs.